# How to backup and restore a database to a different location and name via command line only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database that I want to copy from one location to another (maybe even to a different computer) via the **command line** only.
The name of the database on the new location should not be identical to the original name.

I've tried the following commands, but failed when I tried to restore the database:

Backup:

```
sqlcmd -E -S MyUser\SQLEXPRESS -Q "BACKUP DATABASE original_db TO DISK='C:\tmp\backups\base_db.bak'"
```

Restore:

```
sqlcmd -E -S MyUser\SQLEXPRESS -Q "RESTORE DATABASE new_test_db FROM DISK='C:\tmp\backups\base_db.bak' 
with move 'original_db' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\new_test_db.mdf', 
    move 'original_db' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\new_test_db.ldf'"
```

When I try to restore the database I get the following error:
"The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'new_test_db' database."

(When my database didn't exist I got the following error on restore - "Logical file 'original_db' is not part of database 'new_test_db'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.")

Any ideas how to do it properly?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the restore script: sqlcmd -E -S MyUser\SQLEXPRESS -Q "RESTORE DATABASE new_test_db FROM DISK='C:\tmp\backups\base_db.bak' 
with replace, move 'original_db' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\new_test_db.mdf', 
    move 'original_db_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\new_test_db.ldf'"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`WITH MOVE 'logical_file_name_in_backup'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615.aspx) refers to the internal name of that file, not the database name.

Run this to see what I mean. You're looking at the [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx) column

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

Edit:

Need `WITH REPLACE` now... see first link above and look for

> The database name is different from the database name recorded in the backup set.

Comment: thanks, my database didn't exist, so that's why I got the previous error, I've edited my question. Now the actual problem appears - "The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'new_test_db' database."

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, though now after using both replace and move (+ tried without the move) I'm getting the first error again regarding the file names...any ideas what the full command  should look like? (I'm currently trying to restore the db on the same sqlserver with a different name)

Comment: @Li: Did you change `...with move 'original_db' to...` to `...with move '<insert name from sys.database_files>' to...`?